# swag : The term 'swag' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: powershell, command-line, swagger

My problem is that when I try to run `swag init` I see the following

```
swag : The term 'swag' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ swag init
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (swag:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried every guide there is on stackoverflow and nothing helps changed my env variables every way you can imagine, nothing helped.

My GOPATH is set to %USERPROFILE%\go, this is the folder where I installed go from official site. My Path variable has %USERPROFILE%\go\bin.

Also I get the same error when I try to run another command `go generate` for golang/mock library.

Help me pls) I'll provide any screenshots/info if needed

Comment: I use GoLand, just in case

Comment: I obviously did go get -u github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag before running swag init

Comment: List of possible fixes here : https://github.com/swaggo/swag/issues/197

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming in Go, please don't tag such questions `go` next time.

Comment: @AlainReve tried seting any possible env people suggest on the github page, none of the options work

Answer (score 9):

You need to add Add `$GOPATH/bin` to `$PATH`.
In linux it would be by adding the following to your bash profile:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin
```

Answer (score 9):

If above solution wont work try to install swag like this

```
go install github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag@latest
```

refer this - https://github.com/swaggo/swag

Answer (score 0):

Setting GOBIN env variable to GOPATH/bin helped me.

Comment: how can we set it in windows?

Answer (score 0):

By adding this command to your shell startup file (e.g., .bashrc or .zshrc), you ensure that any executables installed using go install are added to your $PATH and can be executed from anywhere in your terminal.

```
export PATH=$(go env GOPATH)/bin:$PATH
```